# R Markdown and Shiny exchange of objects

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm creating a R Markdown document for the first time and I would like to render Markdown text as well as shiny components in one document, but I do NOT know how to exchange the objects between Markdown and Shiny - any help?

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---
```{r echo=FALSE}
 subjects<-c(letters[1:20])
 inputPanel(selectInput("subject_of_interest","",subjects))
 selected_subject<-input$subject_of_interest # This is failing with error "Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)"
```
The selected subject `r selected_subject` is.....
````

I need to generate other text items based on the selected subject. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will be a start to what you are after.

As you have a `selectInput` you are going to want something to be `reactive` i.e. react to the user input. You therefore create a `reactive function` that will spit out the text you are after. It will be the basics that will get you started.

---

````
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
subjects <- c(letters[1:20])
inputPanel(
 inputPanel(selectInput("subject","Select Subject",subjects,"a"))
)
subject <- reactive({
  paste0(
    "The selected subject ",
  input$subject)
})
output$text <- renderText({ 
          subject()
     })
mainPanel(
      textOutput("text")
    )
```
````

**INLINE EDIT**

As requested, apologies, if you want inline:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
subjects <- c(letters[1:20])
inputPanel(
 inputPanel(selectInput("subject","Select Subject",subjects,"a"))
)
subject <- reactive({
     input$subject
})
output$text <- renderText({ 
          subject()
     })

```
the selected subject `r textOutput("text")`
````

Comment: I have to generate lot of text using other markdown features, what you are saying is I have to use all Shiny output objects to generate the text? Is there a way to assign the selected drop down value to an object that can be accessed in markdown text?

Comment: Question : How can I use the `textOutput("text")` value to subset a data table ? datatable[char==textOutput("text"),] is not working - any help?